# Debug .net core application deployed on local IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have deployed my .net core 2.1 application on local IIS but I can't debug my application. I have also tried attaching with w3wp.exe process of my own created "No managed code" application pool but still can't debug my app.

Updated: I had found a solution to run dotnet.exe and my deployed process together and I succeeded one time but after that dotnet.exe disappeared from the process list and I can't find it anywhere but it exists in C:/ProgramFiles/dotnet I have also tried restarting VS but still no luck. So can I get dotnet.exe process back?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: `w3wp.exe` only loads ASP.NET Core Module and work as reverse proxy, so attaching to it won't work. You need to attach to the actual Kestrel process.

Comment: I cannot fine dotnet.exe in my process list. I restarted VS and it was available in the process list and I debugged my app one time but then it disappeared again and now I can't find it again even after restarting

Comment: Kestrel process would only appear if a request is being processed. Send requests from a web browser, and you should be able to trigger it. Please refer to the document I linked earlier to learn how Visual Studio should be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so with the help of Lex Li comments and google, I have found the solution of debugging Asp.net core app deployed on local IIS.
We need to attach with 2 processes to debug the app

1. dotnet.exe
2. devenv.exe (the title of devenv.exe would be the
       same name by which our app is deployed on IIS.

Note: sometimes we might not find dotnet.exe process in the "Attach to process" list even it would be available in C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet. So we just need to refresh our IIS deployed app on browser and dotnet.exe process will be available in the list then.